# Entity Framework 4.1 DbSet Reload

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using a single instance of `DbContext` scenario to shadow entire copy of the database locally in a WPF app. I've heard this is bad practice, but my database is small and I need an entire copy of it locally while the app is running.

An extension method for `IQueryable`, `Load()` lets me preload the elements of a `DbSet<>`, so that I can bind things to the Local property of `DbSet<>`. Data in the database changes rapidly, so I want to `SaveChanges()` and reload **everything**, even objects that are already tracked. Calling the `Load()` method again doesn't update the items that are tracked but are not marked as changed, which are already loaded.

What is the preferred method of reloading the preloaded items in a `DbSet<>`? Off the top of my head, I can only think of calling `SaveChanges()`, then go through all entries and set both tracked and original values to the current values in the database, then `Load()` whatever new objects that might have been added. In my scenario it's not possible to delete objects, but I might have to support item deletion in the long run. This doesn't seem right, there should be a way to drop everything and reload. It would seem that it's easier to drop my context and just start anew, but all the elements in WPF are already bound to the `Local´ObservableCollection<>`, and this just messes up the interface.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not the way you are supposed to use `DbContext`, and because of that it is almost impossible to reload the data. Keeping a single context around for a long time is [incorrect usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392). The link will also answer why your tracked entities are not updated.

You can selectively reload a single entity by calling `Reload` on `DbEntityEntry`:

```
context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

You can also revert back to `ObjectContext` and use `ObjectQuery` with `MergeOption.OverrideChanges`, or use `Refresh` for a collection of entities with `RefreshMode.StoreWins`.

All these approaches suffers some problems:

- If the record is deleted in the database, it will not be removed from the context.
- Changes in relations are not always refreshed.

The only correct way to get fresh data is `Dispose` the context, create a new one and load everything from scratch - and you are doing this anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am somewhat lost though, because I've read that the exact opposite is preferred in my scenario. I will review these topics, and come back.

Comment: I will have no changes in relations, and no deletions in the database. I'll start another question later today, and try to explain why exactly I can't have a short lived DbContext. I really hope you can weigh in with some valuable input.

Answer (score 8):

With Entity Framework 4.1, the recommendation for WPF data binding has changed to use .Local and a persistent DbContext.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/09/08/data-binding-with-dbcontext.aspx

It's, of course, possible to dispose of it whenever you need to, but it can negatively impact the UI if you do.

Here's another method, but I'm not sure that it takes EF4.1's features into account:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716735.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very confused about the whole .Local thing. Everyone and their dog is telling me not to use a single DbContext for whatever reason, yet it clearly provides this .Local property for long-term binding.

Comment: @Gleno I totally agree with you, IMHO most people use this for ASP in which the context is short lived, but for desktop apps it's just nonsense to reload everything you enter a new form, specially if the info is shared through various forms of your app.

Answer (score 1):

DbContexts are supposed to live short time,
Consider after saving changes disposing it and reloading all from the start.
Have 2 sets of objects.. one from db and another for binding.

Comment: I can't really do this, because then I will lose UI state in the progress. I really wish I could have a short lived DbContext, but I don't see how it's possible in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Please use using() for CRUD.It will automatically reload the updated data.

```
using (myDbContext context = new myDbContext())
{

}
```

Best Regards,
Thet Tin Oo