# EF 4 refresh data

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have an entity something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am reading using LinQ as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer()
{
    var result = from cust in _dbContext.Customers.AsNoTracking() select cust;
    return result;
}
```

First time everything works just fine but when I added a customer in DB manually, the same customer is not reflecting in this query, it always returns the old records.

So how do I always get the updated customers from DB?

Note: I am using EF 4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method call `.AsNoTracking()` The AsNotracking() method is a detached list of the data, verify on the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx in the 5.1 item explains this:

> If you are in a read-only scenario and want to avoid the overhead of
>   loading the objects into the ObjectStateManager, you can issue "No
>   Tracking" queries.  Change tracking can be disabled at the query
>   level.
>
> Note though that by disabling change tracking you are effectively
>   turning off the object cache. When you query for an entity, we can't
>   skip materialization by pulling the previously-materialized query
>   results from the ObjectStateManager. If you are repeatedly querying
>   for the same entities on the same context, you might actually see a
>   performance benefit from enabling change tracking.
>
> When querying using ObjectContext, ObjectQuery and ObjectSet instances
>   will remember a MergeOption once it is set, and queries that are
>   composed on them will inherit the effective MergeOption of the parent
>   query. When using DbContext, tracking can be disabled by calling the
>   AsNoTracking() modifier on the DbSet.

remove the `.AsNoTracking()` for the link query

Comment: even after removing .AsNoTracking() also its still reading the from cache and not reflecting the date in DB.

Comment: I use the above code and it works well. This may depend on how you are entering data in context. When performing the insert you use _dbContext.Customers.Add (customer) .... or performs the insert via SQLComand?

Comment: i have inserted the record manually in DB, so how do i refresh the context?

Comment: In my context I use the `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` with the value true. Check this. If not solve, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799737/entity-framework-4-1-dbset-reload

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this? I have to read the multiple columns using raw sql query    var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string[]>("select ID, NAME, DB_FIELD from eis_hierarchy").ToList(); but not getting the output properly