# Can calling ToList on a DbSet cause caching?

Tags: entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6, sqldependency

I was using the following code to repopulate an `ObservableCollection<T>` on change notification from a `SqlDependency`:

```
var set = _dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
this.AddRange(set);
```

In this scenario, the `OnChange` event fires correctly, but the list is repopulated with the same contents as before. Now I am using the following, second DbContext to populate the list as follows, and now the list is always up to date after a change:

```
using (var dbContext = new XTimeDbContext())
{
    var set = dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
    this.AddRange(set);
}
```

The only difference I can imagine is that the first method's query results are cached. If so, how can I prevent this? If not, why is the list not properly updated?

Comment: Did you have a look à [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799737/entity-framework-4-1-dbset-reload)? Seems to be a similar pb, it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AsNoTracking()` method ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)) to prevent entities from being cached:

```
var set = _dbContext
    .Set<T>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();

this.AddRange(set);
```

Comment: as I pointed out in my question, I don't get caching when I use `using (var dbContext = new XTimeDbContext())`, only when I use the class level `_dbContext`, but 

`var set = _dbContext.Set<T>.AsNoTracking().ToList();`
`this.AddRange(set);`

works a treat, thanks.